# "remote audio recording" greyed out in Windows 10 remote desktop

Tags: windows-10, audio, remote-desktop

As thte title, "remote audio recording" is greyed out in the Windows 10 remote desktop connection setting What can I do?

[image: C:_sharex\Screenshots\2023-06\ShareX-230603T211710-ZAzog1dh~mstsc-Remote_Desktop_Connection.png]

Comment: Solution: Don't select "play on remote computer"

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX, problem solved perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. In the end, my case was remedied by selecting "Listen to this device" on the target computer. For more details, search on "Turn on Listen through a Playback Device" to find the flag which needs to be set as it defaults to disabled.

Of major note is that setting "Remote audio playback" to "Play on remote computer" results in "Remote audio recording" options being greyed out. This behavior is misleading as it suggest the settings are mutually exclusive. After setting the "Turn on Listen through a Playback Device" on the target, the "Remote audio playback" options remain greyed out on the host for that target but the functionality is working.

Several Group Policy edits are commonly listed as fixes to this issue but they did not help in my instance. I've included them below as reference in case they're useful to someone else.

The three group policy changes below are commonly referenced as a solution to this issue with all to be set to either NOT configured or ENABLED. I set all to the latter. All were located within "Computer Configuration | Administrative Templates | Windows Components | Remote Desktop Services"

---

Remote Desktop Session Host | Device and Resource Redirection | Allow Audio and Video Playback Redirection

Remote Desktop Session Host | Device and Resource Redirection | Allow Audio recording Redirection

Remote Desktop Connection Client | RemoteFX USB Device Redirection | Allow RDP redirection of other supported RemoteFX USB devices from this computer.